# Pass NEWID() to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, guid

I have an app in which I cannot do more than one line, thus using a declare seems to be out of the realm of possibly.

I need to create a guid an pass it to a stored procedure.

While in SSMS, I can do

```
SELECT NEWID()
```

and that creates a `uniqueidentifier`.

I also know how to manipulate and declare and set data types in a stored procedure etc..

My problem is that I want to generate a GUID on the fly and pass it as first parameter to the properly done stored procedure.

This is **NOT** working:

```
EXEC dbo.CreateNewbesonUser NEWID(), 0, 'bbad', 0, 'trtr', 0, 0
```

Comment: Stored procedure invocations don't accept expressions, only literals and variables. Declare a variable first (`declare @id uniqueidentifier = newid(); exec .. @id, ...`).

Comment: Oh nice.  thx - create an answer if you want.  thx

Comment: Well, it works in SSMS,  but not in Microsoft System Center Orchestrator Runbook.. :/

Comment: If it will not accept anything but a pure `EXEC`, then your only recourse is to create a new stored procedure  that does nothing exciting except call the first with the `NEWID()` filled in. Alternatively, change the first one to (say) accept `NULL` and make it use `ISNULL(@param, NEWID())`. (Also, if necessary, use Profiler to confirm that it's not doing anything else to the statement that might render it unable to execute -- if you're unlucky *no* sproc call might work.)

Comment: Ok, thanks @JeroenMostert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a variable:

```
DECLARE @u uniqueidentifier;

SET @u = NEWID();

EXEC dbo.CreateNewbesonUser @u, 0, 'bbad', 0, 'trtr', 0, 0;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=85df0977ef7b39396e65cb75129fd030) is an illustrative example in db<>fiddle.

Comment: I needed it to be inline   `declare @id uniqueidentifier = newid(); exec .. @id`, as guy in a comment pointed out.  but this in general works too  thx